# How to create automated tests for android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, frameworks, automated-tests

I have an android application that uses a google map to display markers and I am looking to create automated user acceptance test for the map functions. I will have to grab a marker and click on it to open another activity for example. So I have been looking for the automated test framework like Robotium, Espresso and UIautomator but I could not find any detailed material such as code examples or tutorial on how to create automated GUI tests for a android google map.

Can anyone tell me which framework is the best to realize this kind of automated user acceptance tests and provide with detailed information on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am having to do the same thing  at uni, I have been using Espresso to apply testing to other UI components.  I have not started the map yet, but I found something that might work? I am unsure due to not trying it myself yet (revising).  I had to try and access the android actionbar and to do this I had to refer to the content describtion.  "Navigate Up" is apparently the name of the Home(enabled) function.

```
  onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());  //appbar home icon
```

When a fail occurs due to espresso not reaching a component, it lists all the names and content description of the activity/fragment you are testing within the error output.  (See Below example) Because thats the way i found the name for the android action bar components I enabled. So this might help with your markers etc.

```
 View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=960, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=888, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909173, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=850, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=38.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131492927, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=850, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=766, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=84.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->FrameLayout{id=2131492989, res-name=frame_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=766, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=766, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+---->ActionBarContainer{id=2131492928, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=84, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}   ...

+------>ImageButton{id=-1, desc=Navigate up, visibility=VISIBLE, width=84, height=84, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
```

Can you let me know if it works?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to have some clue about the feature before starting with a framework and to apply your idea, I will have to already chose Espresso without knowing if it will be possible. Anyway, If I try Espresso I will publish the results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a test with Robotium but it could not interact with google apis for authentication because my app is calling external android functions.

Finally, I used UIAutomator to implement this series of tests. It is much simpler if you have to test interaction with external function such as authentication or to take a picture. Grabbing a map marker is as simple a any other UI.

[Boo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2477882/boo) you can also use UIAutomatorViewer to see the document structure.